# WordPress version 3.8 – Preview button not working for editor

Tags: posts, editor, updates, previews

After finishing developing my site, I updated WordPress to version 3.8. Everything works, but for some reason, an editor cannot click on the `Preview` button in the back end. Visiting the link `http://www.domain.com/?p=160&preview=true` manually works though!

I don't know if this is really a version 3.8 problem, as I did not test this before.

Comment: Running 3.8 and do not have that problem, try disabling all plugins and see if that solves it?

Comment: If disabling plugins doesn't fix it, switch to a default WordPress theme -- Twenty Thirteen or Twenty Fourteen.

Comment: Thanks guys. Updating to 3.8.1 solved the problem. There were some problems with ["dead zones" in buttons](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.8.1).

Answer (score 2):

luke reports that this issue has been resolved in the comments of the original question:

> Thanks guys. Updating to 3.8.1 solved the problem. There were some
>   problems with "dead zones" in buttons.